# Image of Jordan measurable set under a diffeomorphism.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling with some basic concepts related to real analysis and multi-variable integral calculus.
I need to prove that if $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a domain, $\Omega\subset U$ is a Jordan measurable set so that $\overline{\Omega} \subset U$ and $T:U\rightarrow T(U)$ is a diffeomorphism, than $T(\Omega)$ is Jordan measurable as well.
I tried to let $\varepsilon > 0$ and cover $\partial \Omega$ with a finite collection of closed rectangles contained in $\{ Q_i \}_{i=1}^N\subset U$ so $\sum_{i=1}^{N}vol ( Q_i ) <\varepsilon$. 
Then I tried to operate $T$ on the rectangles and use the diffeomorphism properties to claim that $T(\partial\Omega) = \partial T(\Omega) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N T(Q_i) \subset T(U)$.
Now I want to operate $T$ on each of the $Q_i$ 's and to say that from uniform continuity of $T$ on each of the rectangles, follows that $vol(T(Q_i)) = \max_{Q_i} \lvert J_T \rvert vol(Q_i)$
But I'm not sure if I can say that $J_T$ (the Jacobian determinant) is bounded.
I start to realize now that it's maybe not the best approach but I ran out of ideas, so I need some hints to get on the track.
Thanks!

Comment: Diffeomorphism has to be at least $C^1$ smooth, i.e., with continuous derivatives. So the Jacobian is bounded on any compact subset of the domain.

Comment: You say that in general? I mean - every diffeomorphism is $C^1$ or that diffeomorphism has to be $C^1$ smooth to preserve Jordan measure?

Comment: If a map is not $C^1$ smooth, I would not call it a diffeomorphism. But you should check the definition in your source.